# Is 'the' article used before a noun that is common and uncountable?

Tags: definite-article

There is a rule that 'the' is used before an uncountable noun but 'the' should always be used before a common noun.
So, if a word is both common and uncountable, then, it is important to use an article as the fact that there should be an article before a common noun and if it is uncountable, 'the' is used ? For example the word, Interaction

Comment: There is no such rule. Please give an actual *sentence* that confuses you.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. _Interaction_ can be either countable or uncountable; when it's uncountable, it _may_ take the definite article.

Comment: Google NGrams are case-sensitive, so [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+interaction+between+you+and%2CThe+interactions+between+you+and&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Interaction+between+you+and%2CInteractions+between+you+and&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly show that sentences can start with all 4 permutations (singular/plural with/without article) of ***[The] Interactions between you and...***

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128164495/the-interaction-of-food-industry-and-environment

Comment: I have provided the link, can't I remove 'the' as interaction is a common noun?

Comment: No. because "the" has nothing to do with it being a common noun.  It has "the" because "interaction" is determined. You know which interaction is being talked about because of the phrase "of Food Industry and Environment"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nouns that are common and uncountable, for example "rice", can be used in noun phrases with an article "the", or another determiner, or no determiner.  They should not be used with the article "a", this this means one item, which is not possible with an uncountable noun. So

> I ate the rice that came with the curry.

> My rice was overcooked.

> I had rice for dinner.

But not

> *I had a rice for dinner

With the word "interaction".  This can be countable or uncountable:

> There was an interaction between the drugs.  (countable)

> This job involves a lot of interaction with customers (non-count, no "the")

> The interaction between management and workers got worse. (ambiguous. could be count or non-count, with very little difference in meaning)

> The interactions of the characters are central to the plot ("the", countable, plural)

> The first interaction was positive  (countable singular, with "the")

The use of "the" is about whether the noun is determined or not, and does not indicate if the noun is countable. Nor does it indicate if a noun is common or proper.

Comment: Here is the link - https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128164495/the-interaction-of-food-industry-and-environment

Comment: In this, can I remove 'the' before the word, Interaction? or is it required as the interaction is a common noun ?

Comment: The word "the" is used correctly in the title of the book. In this case it is ambiguous if the word is countable on uncountable, but it is irrelevant (since there is no practical difference in meaning)